# NullPointerException in Android Custom Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app, i uses Android Custom View for displaying some log info.  In that view i want to change a item's color on the basis of some criteria.  I tried with below code it causes NullPointerException in getView.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
        View row = convertView;
        ItemHolder holder = null;

        if( row == null ){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResouceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ItemHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtPhoneno = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lvphoneno);
            holder.txtDateTime = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lvdatetime);
            holder.txtSerialno = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lvserialno);
            holder.txtStatus = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lvstatus);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ItemHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        MyListViewItem item = items.get(position);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(item.icon);
        holder.txtPhoneno.setText(item.phoneno);
        holder.txtDateTime.setText(item.datetime);
        holder.txtSerialno.setText(item.serialno);

        if( !item.status.isEmpty()){
            if( -1 != item.status.indexOf("OK"))
                holder.txtStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            else
                holder.txtStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

        holder.txtStatus.setText(item.status);
        return row;         
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Helper.Log(getContext(), e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

but an interesting thing, when i remove below lines it works fine

```
        if( !item.status.isEmpty()){
            if( -1 != item.status.indexOf("OK"))
                holder.txtStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            else
                holder.txtStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
```

logcat

```
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1432)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1302)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1576)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    12-15 07:04:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me to solve this problem

thanks

Comment: You should always post your LogCat when your app crashes, but I took a guess anyway.

Comment: why are you returning null in `getView()` outside of the exception block, - that smells bad!!!! As for NPE itself, are you certain that `layoutResouceId` is the actual resource for `row` which **should** be non-null? If that's the case, then the NPE is coming from elsewhere - logcat please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wager that `status` is null:

```
if( -1 != item.status.indexOf("OK"))
```

`item` is obviously not null and assuming that `holder.txtStatus.setText()` doesn't throw an NPE either, this only leaves `status`...

(But without more information I cannot hep you beyond this.)

Comment: i modified my question with null status checker and logcat

Comment: What API are you testing this on?

Comment: input data for listview is coming from a database.  I checked the value of status, it is null not empty.  i changed to check the value for null.  now it is working, anyway thanks

Comment: @kTekkie Why did you not mention that the data for listview is coming from database? - Please enclose all information in future!

Comment: @t0mm13b sorry i am newbie to java/android, thanks for notifying